# In DAX how could i calculate top 5 and others sum with percentage

Tags: powerbi, dax, data-analysis

I have a table which incluede firms name and cities
i want to calculate percectage of top 5 cities and sum of other cities

my expectatiton is:

| city | firms % |
| --- | --- |
| ny | 25 |
| ca | 20 |
| fl | 15 |
| az | 12 |
| others | 28 |

Comment: What is the structure of the data you are aggregating

Comment: It is 1000startup dataset
It has one overview table which includes startupname, state, city, industry etc